# How to resolve conflicting import requirements when importing both from and within a subdirectory?

Tags: python, spyder

I have a project with the following structure:

```
./script.py
./modules/__init__.py
./modules/mod1.py
./modules/mod2.py
```

I need to import `mod2` in `mod1.py`, and both `mod1` and `mod2` in `script.py`. For ease of testing, I'd also like to sometimes run the `mod1.py` file as a script (using `if __name__== "__main__":`). However, I'm observing the following:

- In `script.py`, I include `from modules import mod1` and `from modules import mod2`.
- If I include `import mod2` in `mod1.py`, I can run `mod1.py`...
- ...But then if I try to run `script.py`, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'mod2'`. I can modify `mod1.py` to instead use `from modules import mod2`, and then `script.py` runs...
- ... But then if I try to run just `mod1.py`, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'modules'`.

I've searched around this site and found several questions addressing just importing within a directory and importing from a subdirectory, but haven't been able to find anything on resolving the conflicting requirements between the two. What am I missing?

EDIT: I am running all of my projects through Spyder's IPython console, so a solution that works with this workflow would be extra helpful.

Comment: I don't have a problem when I try to run `mod1.py` with the code you suggest....

Comment: @user32882 I am running all of my scripts through Spyder - that might make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use absolute imports:

```
from modules import mod1
from modules import mod2
```

and run everything from the root directory using [-m option](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m):

```
python -m script
python -m modules.mod1
python -m modules.mod2
```

Comment: To clarify, this means that the modules can/should never be run as scripts from their subdirectory?

Comment: Yes, this is ok only for modules in root directory (that is: `python script.py`). Submodules inside packages should not be executed this way.

Answer (score 0):

@Piotr Praszmo's answer works. Based on that answer, I found that for the specific case of running the scripts in Spyder, using absolute imports everywhere and then changing the working directory in the `runfile` command to the root directory solved my problem:

```
runfile('./modules/mod1.py', wdir='./')
```